# Accessing the contents of a topic

Tags: python, html, css, django, view

How do I pass the id of a model that is within a model

model.py

```
class Topic(models.Model):

    """ A topic the user is learning about """

    text = models.CharField(max_length = 200) 
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE) 

    def __str__(self):

        return self.text 

class Entry(models.Model):

    enttopic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete = models.CASCADE) 
    text = models.TextField() 

    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True) 


    class Meta:

        verbose_name_plural = 'entries'

    def __str__(self):

        return self.text


class Document(models.Model):

    doctopic = models.ForeignKey(Entry, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to = 'documents/', blank = True, null=True)
    upload_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
```

As you can see, Entry model belongs to Topic, and Document belongs to Entry.

Topic>Entry>Document.

Now, I know how to get the contents of Entry through Topic.

views.py

```
def topic(request, topic_id):

    topic = Topic.objects.get(id = topic_id)
    entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
    images = topic.image_set.order_by('-upload_at') 

    context = {'topic': topic, 'entries':entries, 'images': images}

    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topic.html', context)
```

But how do  I get the contents of Document through Entry? I don't want a hyperlink.

I wanted to be so that once someone clicks on the Topic, the Entry and Documents should be revealed at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the documents like that:

```
topic = Topic.objects.get(id = topic_id)
entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
documents = Document.objects.filter(doctopic__in=entries)
```

Comment: Works perfectly.